# System.Text.json JsonSerializer unicode issue on read from json file

Tags: c#, unicode, system.text.json

In an C# .net core environment, using the System.Text.Json unicode characters are substituted. For example "ü" is shown after reading the json file into a list of an object into another symbol

```
Passwort zurücksetzen
```

becomes

```
Passwort zur�cksetzen
```

I tried to set the json options:

```
JsonSerializerOptions jso = new JsonSerializerOptions();
jso.Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping;
this.messageTemplates = 
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MessageTemplate>>(messageTemplateJsonData, jso);
```

This did not change the behavior.

Any idea?

**Update: issue resolved**

As suspected by diogoaos the problem does not occur in the json deserializer, but upfront, when the json doc in read in from a file. So the solution was to save the file as utf-8 and to setup encoding for the file reader:

```
string messageTemplateJsonData = File.ReadAllText(messageTemplatesFilename, System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8);
JsonSerializerOptions jso = new JsonSerializerOptions();
jso.Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping;
this.messageTemplates = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MessageTemplate>>(messageTemplateJsonData, jso);
```

Comment: How are you displaying your data?  You have non-ASCII Unicode characters, which can only be displayed if your UI or console is setup for the proper character set.

Comment: I print the data to console. But the console normally shows an "ü"

Comment: Are you on a different computer?  Did you change your code page?  If you're using a code page that doesn't have a "ü", that's what you'd see.  Is the file stored as Unicode, or does it just assume an encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a problem that occurs out of this context. Maybe you are transfering this string between components that doesn't have the same default encoding or is reading a file that has a different encoding than the default encoding of your CLR.

In a comment on your question, you say "I print the data to console". Can you print the raw string (before the desserialization, this messageTemplateJsonData object)? Is he character showing correctly?

Or you could create a string internally with this character (not read externally, but make a literal in your code) and see if the error occurs.

I tried to reproduce this problem on a Csharp notebook (in vscode), and got a correct result, but this is .Net 6 so it could be a version problem.

[image: Trying to reproduce the error]

Comment: You are right! The issue started on reading the json from file. I had to save the file in utf-8 format and the special characters have been displayed as expected. Thanks!